# Continuous renormalisation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*, M.D. Schwartz talks about how Wilsonian renormalisation relates to continuous renormalisation. He states that continuous renormalisation

> looks a lot like the linear approximation to the Wilsonian RGE.

Since he introduced both of them through lots of examples and we only did the Wilsonian method in my course I am having trouble working out what continuous renormalisation actually is and if it is an approximation to Wilson's approach or an independent method.

Comment: I would assume continuous renormalization is simply renormalization without introducing a lattice parameter (_i.e._ working in the continuum). I don't know about the _exact_ relationship between the two, but in renormalizable theories, the exact details of renormalization do not matter, and all ways to go about it should lead to the same results.